# Remove all documents from each collection with the matched query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to remove all documents with the matched query in mongodb. which means there will be a field "head" in all collections. i want to remove all documents in each collection with head is matched with id : 128643 using **single query.** How can i do that with mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend spending time in the mongoose documentation, it’s pretty easy to find there...

The command you’re looking for is [Model.deleteMany()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany)

So in your case, it would be `Model.deleteMany({ id: 128643 });`

Comment: thanks for the response. But my question is, i want to remove those documents with single query in my database. i dont want to select each collection and apply deleteMany command.